# What is "well attenuated maltiness"?

Tags: beer, flavor, bjcp, pilsner

I am studying to become a BJCP judge.

I was reading through [Style 2a German Pilsner](http://www.bjcp.org/styles04/Category2.php#style2A) and saw something in the flavor profile that I didn't quite understand thoroughly.

It says

> Moderate to moderately-low yet ***well attenuated maltiness***, although some grainy flavors and slight malt sweetness are acceptable

What does this mean?

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like malty flavor, without the sweetness of, say, a scottish beer.   A dry maltiness.

Comment: +1 I agree, I would think it means low residual sweetness without losing maltiness, too.

Answer (score 1):

I read it as being fermented dry enough so that its crisp like you'd expect that style to be.  But in-order to retain a maltiness while drying the beer out its becomes a matter of choosing great ingredients.  This is where using the best Continental Pilsner malt available comes into play.  Great german pilsner is about a near perfect fermentation to let the work of the maltster really shine through.